# PHP and WordPresss require?

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, requirements

What PHP version does WordPress require? 
I am not sure what are the hosting requirements for my WordPress theme. I am using a theme exported from https://themesgenerator.com/ and I am afraid I need different versions depending on the selected theme.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about the WordPress core, or about the theme?

Comment: Questions about WordPress are out of scope here at Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Wordpress 5.x.x, https://wordpress.org/download/

- Recommend servers running version 7.3 or greater of PHP.
- MySQL version 5.6 OR MariaDB version 10.0 or greater.
- Recommend either Apache or Nginx.

Wordpress Theme should have indicated the Wordpress Version that it supports.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is this the latest version?

Comment: @EstherF Assuming that you are hosting your own Wordpress. According to the Wordpress.org Download, it is the latest system/software requirement.